# How can I access my local Website with other networks?

Tags: apache, raspberry-pi

At the moment I am setting up a Webserver(Apache2 using HTML,PHP and CSS) on my raspberry pi 3B+. However I know that this Website is only accessible using the local Ip Address of my Raspberry. So I can only access my Website using the ip of the Raspberry and being in the same network. 
I was wondering if it is possible to setup the Raspberry to access the Server from anywhere/different networks and of course how i can achieve it.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at project Ngrok, it allows to expose your local webserver with an external url. (provided by it).

Once you download is as easy as

```
./ngrok http 80
```